# JavaScript parentheses (1,2,3,4,5)

Tags: javascript, namespaces, closures, parentheses

I just came across some notation in JavaScript like so:

```
var a = (1,2,3,4,5);
```

This will always return the last value, in the above case `5`.  I'm aware of using brackets to namespace my JavaScript code, but have never seen it used this way.

Is there any use for this notation, or is it just some JavaScript byproduct?

Comment: Brackets or parentheses?

Comment: Can you post the actual code you saw used this way? Your sample is of course utterly useless as an expression.

Comment: This is a property of the comma, not the parentheses.

Comment: This can be used to execute arbitrary expression with side-effects within an unrelated expression or a declaration block

Comment: _"I'm aware of using brackets to namespace my JavaScript code"_ - Parentheses don't create namespaces. If you are talking about an immediately executed function expression `(function(){...})()` the function is the key part to that technique - the parens around the anonymous function are just one of several ways that you can ensure the function is treated as an expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the comma operator. As the mdn states ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)) it always returns the later value. In your example it doesn't make much sense, since it will always assign `a = 5`. But consider this:

```
for (var i = 0, j = 9; i <= 9; i++, j--) {
    ...
}
```

It's used to increment and decrement in a single statement: `i++, j--`

#### Edit:

The parentheses in your example are necessary because its a variable declaration. In other cases they can be left out.

Comment: "in your example the parentheses can be stripped" - no (note `var` before).

Answer (score -1):

Parens are used to groups operations together. This is helpful for both setting operation precedence (e.g. x = (2+3) * 5 vs x = 2 + 3 * 5) and for making your code a little easier to read.

I suspect this is more a question about the comma operator. This is for making multiple assignments or operations on the same line. Here is a nice article about it: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/the-javascript-comma-operator/

Comment: **-1** Did you test your code that "works the same way"? Parentheses are for operator precedence, and the comma operator has lower precedence than assinment.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Maybe I should think before I type next time. Sorry.